# set outer closure values inside inner closure invokation

Tags: groovy

I have a facility like this

```
class Core {

    def call(Closure c) {
        c.delegate = this
        c()
        this
    }

    def slide = { title, closure ->
        def slideWriter = new SlideWriter()
        closure.delegate = slideWriter
        closure()
        slideWriter
    }

    private class SlideWriter {

        def text = { position, closure ->
            def value
            closure.delegate = text
            closure()
            println "Value: " + value // null
        }
    }
}

def c = new Core()

c {
    slide ("title") {
        text(1) {
            value = "Some text"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to set the value of `def value` using closure, passed to `text` invokation.

But it displays `Value: null`.
Why is that and how to set `value` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can.

You can, however, change slide to this

```
def slide = { title, closure ->
    def slideWriter = new SlideWriter()
    closure.delegate = slideWriter
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure()
    slideWriter
}
```

and `SlideWriter` to

```
private class SlideWriter {
    def value
    def text = { position, closure ->
        closure()
        println "Value: " + value // null
    }
}
```

And it should work

Comment: Hm, what gives changing strategy to `DELEGATE_FIRST`. Wouldn't it looked into delegate anyway?

Comment: http://victorsavkin.com/post/4135607663/groovy-resolve-strategies it just sets the value as a script level variable as it checks the owner (the script) first